# Error when updating my Ruby version using RVM on Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I tried to update Ruby in my Mac OS X 10.6.6 system. Now I have 1.8.7, and I want to update to 1.9.2.
When I typed `rvm install 1.9.2` I got:

```
gal-harths-iMac:~ galharth$ rvm install 1.9.2
/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /Users/galharth/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  ', please read /Users/galharth/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I installed XCode and it still doesn't work.

This is the configure.log file:

```
[2011-02-08 17:10:04]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/galharth/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
[2011-02-08 17:23:19]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/galharth/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
[2011-02-08 20:44:14]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/galharth/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
[2011-02-08 21:02:55]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/galharth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/galharth/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Did you do as the error message indicates and read /Users/galharth/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/configure.log?   What did it tell?

Comment: 10x for the comment i edited my qustion, an added the configure.log file..

Comment: Can you include the output of `echo $PATH` and also `which gcc` from the command line?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE; you need a C compiler. gcc comes with the Mac OS X Developer Tools, so try downloading that.

Comment: XCode is the name of the development environment, which includes the compiler, make, all the headers etc. Downloading and installing XCode will install all the development tools.

Answer (score 3):

There are some oddities in your log file output. Your question shows you have Mac OS 10.6.6, but the log shows the OS is i386. Mac OS 10.6.6 should be x86_64. This means for some reason your system thinks it's 32-bit when it should be 64bit. Your version of [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) needs to be current, so if you didn't just download it and install it, then do so. The version of [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) on the Snow Leopard disk was buggy, and the version for Mac OS prior to Snow Leopard is out of date once you install 10.6 on your machine.

Here's some things to try. If one works you're done, otherwise try the next one.

1. Do `rvm -v` and note the version number, then `rvm get head` followed by `rvm reload` if the version number displayed after updating has changed. Try running `rvm install 1.9.2-p136`.
2. Delete the files in your `~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136` directory using `rm ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136`, then try installing using the install command in #1.
3. Manually download a copy of [Ruby 1.9.2-p136](ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org:21//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz) into your `~/.rvm/archives` directory and extract it into your `~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136` directory. You can `cd ~/.rvm/archives`, delete any existing old version of the archive, then use `curl -O ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org:21//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz` or `wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org:21//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz` to pull in a new version. Then `cd ~/.rvm/src` then the `rm` command from #2 above followed by `tar zxvf ../archives/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz` to extract the files, then try running the RVM install command in #1.

I have a machine that's behind a proxy that won't allow RVM to get to the Ruby repositories, causing the archive to actually be the proxy's failure notice. When RVM tried burst the tar file, it would fail, but not catch the problem, then would try to configure and fail. The fix was to manually download the archive and burst it into the `src` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Using the command `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I inserted the Snow Leopard disk, selected Optional Installs and installed the Xcode package. That solved the missing C compiler problem as described here.  Thanks to this blog: http://www.brianp.net/2009/09/05/snow-leopards-ate-my-c-compiler/

In my case, once I solved the compiler problem I got a permissions error.  Running as root in bash gave rvm the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Lion check to make sure you have the Command Line Tools installed.  They separated them from XCode so they are a separate download now. You can find them here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action